# How would I validate User input (names only / no numbers) using an if statement

Tags: java

The following takes in 10 names and then prints them using `System.out.println` later. I have an if statement below when I enter a number it warns me "do no enter numbers".

The problem is that after the warning prompt I enter 10 names but the number prints off as the first item in the Array? Then the names print afterwards?

```
import java.io.*;


public class Input {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] myarray = new String[10];


        System.out.println("Enter a 10 names");


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {


            myarray[i] = br.readLine();
            if (!myarray[i].matches("[a-zA-Z_]+")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid name,please do not enter numbers");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Here are your names");


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            System.out.println(myarray[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the code you are running? Nothing is writting to `myarray`. Also because of how the for loop is set up, when a number is entered, then you will skip that entry.

Comment: where did the "info" array come from?

Comment: Sorry I renamed the info to myarray

Comment: Augusto I'm not sure what you mean nothing is written to the array because after the prompt to enter names I enter 10 names and they are printed afterwards ..the issue is that when I enter a number to start with that number is stored in an Array,(then I enter names after the error prompt) but the first element of the array is the number i Just entered before the error check.

Comment: Instead of adding `br.readLine()` to the array, check whether it is valid and then either add it to the array or discard it accordingly. In the latter case, don't increment `i`.

Comment: I forgot to mention this isn't homework.jsheeran could you just me a quick example?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you're rejecting a value you're incrementing the loop counter as if you'd accepted it.

Instead of writing the input to the array, check whether it is valid first:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
  String line = br.readLine();
  if (line.matches("[a-zA-Z_]+") {
    myarray[i++] = line;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Invalid name");
  }
}
```

Note that `i` is only incremented when a value is written to the array, and `while` is used in preference to `for` since the number of iterations is unknown.